# PHP order array acording to another array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one has string elements and the other one has exactly the position where those elements are supposed to be. In the second array key represents a position and the value represents where the value from the first array is supposed to be. But I cant not manage make it work. This is the code that I have so far:

```
<?php
$array1= array("d","c","b","e","a");
$poss  = array (3  ,2  ,1  ,4  ,0);
var_dump(orderArray($poss, $array1));

function orderArray($poss, $data){
    $countPoss = count($poss);
    $countData = count($data);
    if ($countPoss === $countData){
        for ($i=0; $i<$countData; $i++){
            if($poss[$i]!==$i){
                $aux = $data[$i];
                $data = insertArrayIndex($data, $aux, $poss[$i]);
                unset($data[$i]);
                $data = array_values($data);
            }
        }
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
    return $data;
}
function insertArrayIndex($array, $new_element, $index) {
     $start = array_slice($array, 0, $index); 
     $end = array_slice($array, $index);
     $start[] = $new_element;
     return array_merge($start, $end);
 }
```

In other words, `$array1` is supposed to be organized according to `$poss`. E.g.: the first element in `$array1` 'd' is supposed in in position 3 at the end, and 'a' is supposed to be in position 0.
I've been trying hundreds of things, but I can not figure it out.

Comment: can you please provide answer

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you can do something like this: `$new_array = array_combine($poss, $array1); asort($new_array);`

Comment: Did you get your answer? If not post your expected result

Comment: @wti Would be great if you could accept the answer (if it helped) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to [combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) your arrays and then [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) the result while maintaining the index association :)

```
// given
$array1= array("d","c","b","e","a");
$poss  = array (3  ,2  ,1  ,4  ,0);

// combine
$indexedArray = array_combine($poss,$array1);

// sort
asort($indexedArray);

// test
print_r($indexedArray);
```

which results to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try using `array_combine`

```
// since keys are aligned with words you can combine into single array
$merged_array = array_combine($poss, $array1);
// then sort array by keys and your words are in correct position
ksort($merged_array);

// update $array1 with sorted values 
$array1 = array_values($merged_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you program this as an exercise then I wish you patience and good luck!

But if you need this code in production then you better use the PHP sorting functions instead of reinventing the wheel.

#### Solution #1

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create a new array having `$poss` as keys and `$array1` as values then use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort this new array using its keys:

```
$array1= array("d","c","b","e","a");
$poss  = array (3  ,2  ,1  ,4  ,0);

$out1 = array_combine($poss, $array1);
ksort($out1);
print_r($out1);
```

#### Solution #2

Use the function [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to sort `$poss` **and** `$array1` on the same time. The first argument of `array_multisort()` tells the order, the values of the other arrays follow the movements of the values in the first array:

```
$array1= array("d","c","b","e","a");
$poss  = array (3  ,2  ,1  ,4  ,0);

array_multisort($poss, $array1);
print_r($array1);
```

**The output of both methods:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can get the array with correct indexes

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($poss as $key => $value)
  $newarray[$value] = $array1[$key];
var_dump($newarray);
```

And so with correct indexes and order

```
$newarray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($poss); $i++) {
  $newarray[] = $array1[array_search($i, $poss)];
}
var_dump($newarray);
```